# Simple Question about Derivative property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and $f(-1) = f(1) = 0$ and $f(0) = 1$. Prove that there exists $x_0 \in (-1,1)$ with $f''(x_0) = -2$.

I tried establishing this with multiple applications of the MVT, and the intermediate value property of derivatives, but to no avail. I also tried with Taylor's Theorem to no avail. Trying to avoid integration of any sort. Any hints or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Have you considered $f(x) + x^2$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair In what sense?

Comment: In the sense of proving that its 2nd derivative is 0 somewhere in the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Paul Sinclair mentioned in the comment, consider $g(x)=f(x)+x^2$.

Since $g(-1)=g(0)=g(1) =1$ , by MVT(or Rolle's theorem), $\exists\, x_1,\, x_2, \,  -1<x_1<0, \,0<x_2<1$  such that $g'(x_1) =0,\, g'(x_2)=0$. Again, $\exists,\, x_0,\, x_1<x_0<x_2$, such that $g''(x_0)=f''(x_0)+2=0$, which means $f''(x_0)=-2$.

As a remark, a similar technique is used in proving MVT from Rolle's theorem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: The question asks for a point where $f''(x_0) = -2$.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Just making sure, no worries. Any idea how to prove it without considering $g(x)$?

Comment: Without considering $g(x)$, maybe we can try splitting the problem into many cases, many intermediate points, and prove them one by one.

Comment: This is what I tried initially, but there seemed to be something missing. There were a lot of cases, and it was quite annoying. Though, I'm not sure I would have seen the trick of adding $x^2$.

Comment: Since most techniques involve finding zeros, l set $f'' - 2$ = 0 and integrated twice